# How to find permission level date(Last Modifed or Created) for a user and group?

Tags: permissions, groups, spuser

How to find permission level date(Last Modifed or Created) which applying permission level for a user and group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any method or way you can find out last modified date of permission level for a user or group in SharePoint 2007 or 2010 at the moment unless there's a hack to find out but I think it will be rare, why you need to know it tho.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is correct... even if you got the last time an item was modified, or compared a modified date/time to a version, nothing gets recorded into version history for a permission change.  Maybe something on the SQL side, buried in the content database blob data, records it, but then you're looking at database scripting and there, you'd have to know what you're looking for with all the "FileLeafRef" references all over...